# Behavior DependencyProperty not updating ViewModel when used within DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties, behavior

I have a `DependencyProperty` in a `Behavior` which I am setting the value for in `OnAttached()`.

I am then binding view model properties to this `DependencyProperty` with a `Mode` of `OneWayToSource`.

For some reason the bound view model property does not get updated by the `OneWayToSource` binding when done within a `DataTemplate` (the view model's setter is never invoked).  In other circumstances it appears to work fine.

I'm getting no binding errors and I can see no indications of any exceptions, etc, and am at a loss as to what it is I am doing wrong.

The WPF Designer *does* show some errors, claiming either `The member "TestPropertyValue" is not recognized or is not accessible` or `The property "TestPropertyValue was not found in type 'TestBehavior'`, depending on where you look.  I am unsure if these are 'real' errors (as I've observed the WPF Designer does not seem to be entirely reliable in always showing genuine issues), and if they are, are whether they are related to this issue or another problem entirely.

If these Designer errors do relate to this issue I can only assume that I must have declared the `DependencyProperty` incorrectly.  If that is the case I am unable to see where the mistakes are.

I have produced an example project that replicates the issue.  The following code should suffice and can be added to any new WPF project with the name `WpfBehaviorDependencyPropertyIssue001`.

###### MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfBehaviorDependencyPropertyIssue001.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:tb="clr-namespace:WpfBehaviorDependencyPropertyIssue001.Behaviors"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfBehaviorDependencyPropertyIssue001.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding TestPropertyValue, ElementName=OuterTestA}" Background="Cyan">
            <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <tb:TestBehavior x:Name="OuterTestA" TestPropertyValue="{Binding MainTestValueA, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
            </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Label>
        <Label Content="{Binding MainTestValueA, Mode=OneWay}" Background="Orange" />
        <Label Content="{Binding MainTestValueB, Mode=OneWay}" Background="MediumPurple" />
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
            <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <tb:TestBehavior x:Name="OuterTestB" TestPropertyValue="{Binding MainTestValueB, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
            </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="{Binding TestPropertyValue, ElementName=InnerTest}" Background="Cyan">
                            <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <tb:TestBehavior x:Name="InnerTest" TestPropertyValue="{Binding ItemTestViewModelValue, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                            </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </Label>
                        <Label Content="{Binding ItemTestViewModelValue, Mode=OneWay}" Background="Lime" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

###### TestBehavior.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfBehaviorDependencyPropertyIssue001.Behaviors
{
    public class TestBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
    {
        public static DependencyProperty TestPropertyValueProperty { get; } = DependencyProperty.Register("TestPropertyValue", typeof(string), typeof(TestBehavior));

        // Remember, these two are just for the XAML designer (or I guess if we manually invoked them for some reason).
        public static string GetTestPropertyValue(DependencyObject dependencyObject) => (string)dependencyObject.GetValue(TestPropertyValueProperty);
        public static void SetTestPropertyValue(DependencyObject dependencyObject, string value) => dependencyObject.SetValue(TestPropertyValueProperty, value);

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            SetValue(TestPropertyValueProperty, "Example");
        }
    }
}
```

###### ViewModelBase.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfBehaviorDependencyPropertyIssue001.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

###### MainViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfBehaviorDependencyPropertyIssue001.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
        {
            get => _Items;
            set
            {
                _Items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _Items;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>()
            {
                new ItemViewModel() { ItemName="Item 1" }
            };
        }

        public string MainTestValueA
        {
            get => _MainTestValueA;
            set
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Setting {nameof(MainTestValueA)} to {(value != null ? $"\"{value}\"" : "null")}");
                _MainTestValueA = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainTestValueA));
            }
        }
        private string _MainTestValueA;

        public string MainTestValueB
        {
            get => _MainTestValueB;
            set
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Setting {nameof(MainTestValueB)} to {(value != null ? $"\"{value}\"" : "null")}");
                _MainTestValueB = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainTestValueB));
            }
        }
        private string _MainTestValueB;
    }
}
```

###### ItemViewModel.cs

```
namespace WpfBehaviorDependencyPropertyIssue001.ViewModels
{
    public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string ItemName
        {
            get => _ItemName;
            set
            {
                _ItemName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemName));
            }
        }
        private string _ItemName;

        public string ItemTestViewModelValue
        {
            get => _ItemTestViewModelValue;
            set
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Setting {nameof(ItemTestViewModelValue)} to {(value != null ? $"\"{value}\"" : "null")}");
                _ItemTestViewModelValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemTestViewModelValue));
            }
        }
        private string _ItemTestViewModelValue;
    }
}
```

*Expected* Debug output messages (excluding the standard WPF ones):

```
Setting MainTestValueA to null
Setting MainTestValueA to "Example"
Setting MainTestValueB to null
Setting MainTestValueB to "Example"
Setting ItemTestViewModelValue to null
Setting ItemTestViewModelValue to "Example"
```

*Actual* Debug output messages (excluding the standard WPF ones):

```
Setting MainTestValueA to null
Setting MainTestValueA to "Example"
Setting MainTestValueB to null
Setting MainTestValueB to "Example"
Setting ItemTestViewModelValue to null
```

Comment: I think attached props should get registered with 'RegisterAttached'.
Also in the ctor you set the value "Example" to the instance of the TestBehaviour object itself, while in the static Get/Set methods you get/set the values from/to the dependency object passed in, which are the controls/labels in your xaml. So the values are mapped to different targets...

Comment: @lidqy `TestPropertyValue` is not an attached property.  It is a dependency property on `TestBehavior`.  The binding on the labels themselves is for demonstrating the problem.  The key bit to focus on is the bindings on the `TestBehavior` elements themselves.  Also, the `AssociatedObject` for the behavior is not used in this example, meaning the dependency property value is _not_ being stored with the labels.

Comment: @lidqy Also, the reason this is not being done as an attached property to begin with is because this is ultimately being used in a larger project where I _am_ making use of `AssociatedObject` for the `Behavior`.  In reproducing the problem I am experiencing, those pieces of functionality are superfluous.  Finally, the value of "Example" is not being set in a constructor, it is being set in the `OnAttached()` method of the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue.

For some reason, it looks like an `UpdateSourceTrigger` of `PropertyChanged` is needed for a binding within a `DataTemplate` that has a `Mode` of `OneWayToSource`.
Doing this results in the view model property being updated correctly.

I discovered this through experimentation, and I am uncertain why this behaviour differs from the binding done outside the `DataTemplate`, although it is possible that this behaviour is documented somewhere.

If I can find the reason for this behaviour (documented or not) I will update this answer with that information.

#### Additional information

For clarity for future readers, the label with the `OneWayToSource` binding *outside* of the `DataTemplate` worked as expected.  The XAML for this (from the original question) is shown below:

```xml
        <Label Content="{Binding TestPropertyValue, ElementName=OuterTestA}" Background="Cyan">
            <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <tb:TestBehavior x:Name="OuterTestA" TestPropertyValue="{Binding MainTestValueA, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
            </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Label>
```

However, the `TestBehavior` with the `OneWayToSource` binding *within* the `DataTemplate` did not work.  The XAML for this (from the original question) is shown below:

```xml
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="{Binding TestPropertyValue, ElementName=InnerTest}" Background="Cyan">
                            <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <tb:TestBehavior x:Name="InnerTest" TestPropertyValue="{Binding ItemTestViewModelValue, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                            </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </Label>
                        <Label Content="{Binding ItemTestViewModelValue, Mode=OneWay}" Background="Lime" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the `TestBehavior` binding resulted in the view model property being updated correctly.  The updated XAML is shown below:

```xml
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="{Binding TestPropertyValue, ElementName=InnerTest}" Background="Cyan">
                            <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <tb:TestBehavior x:Name="InnerTest" TestPropertyValue="{Binding ItemTestViewModelValue, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                            </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </Label>
                        <Label Content="{Binding ItemTestViewModelValue, Mode=OneWay}" Background="Lime" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code completely and it works fine.

Your Debug works well because all members are called at once when an instance of the `MainViewModel` is created.

The `MainTestValueA` is called with a value of null, then `OnPropertyChanged` is called and `bind` to the label control is called with the `TestPropertyValue` property and with that `OnAttached` method which initializes the `example` and prints it on the output.

The same steps for `MainTestValueB`
And the same steps are repeated for `ItemTestViewModelValue` but because it is inside `DataGridView` `clr` does not allow access from View.

***Of course, this is my conclusion.***

Comment: 1/2 The changes you have supplied do not resolve the issue, and also, I confess, do not make much sense in the context of the problem (although I did try them regardless).  First, you have added a local `TestValueProperty` property but not removed the static `GetTestPropertyValue` and `SetTestPropertyValue` methods.  These are two different approaches of doing the same thing to identify the dependency property in XAML.  It makes no sense to have both, but there's no functional difference between them. (continued)

Comment: 2/2 Second, calling `SetValue()` for the property in its own PropertyChanged callback seems bizarre.  What was your reasoning behind this?  If WPF didn't restrict raising the event to _only_ when the effective value of the dependency property changes this would result in an infinite loop.  You are effectively saying 'if the dependency property value has changed, change it again to the same value we have just changed it to'.

Third, I explicitly want the property to be `OneWayToSource`, _not_ `TwoWay`.  I don't want the view model to be updating the dependency property value, only reading it.

Comment: In response to your edit, I'm aware the code I supplied in the question works apart from the binding for the `Behavior` within the `DataTemplate`, for which there are no errors, etc, it just fails to set the value of the view model property. It's possible you're touching on this at the end of your answer where you state "but because it is inside `DataGridView` `clr` does not allow access from View.", however I'm afraid I am unsure what it is you are trying to say. Normal data binding usually works fine within the `RowDetailsTemplate` of a `DataGrid`. Are you able to elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: I tracked the program and when I got to ItemTestViewModelValue the debugger returned to Items with the value "Example" and because the item is bind to DataGridView I did this clr did not enter the definition (public string itemTestViewModelValue).

Comment: If I understand what you're saying correctly, you have discovered the issue that my question is asking about.  I am well aware that it does not invoke the `ItemTestViewModelValue` setter as it should, and I endeavoured to make this fact obvious with the addition of the debug messages which you would have seen in the `Debug` view of the `Output` window in Visual Studio.  I also included the output messages in the question itself to try and make this as clear as possible.  I am trying to discover why this behaviour is occurring and whether or not this issue can be resolved.